# Account Team Access functionality

Tags: sharing, account, account-teams, access-modifier

I have a question on Account access setting while adding Account Team.

1. I have Account sharing rule that provides Read-Write access to a Role (R1).
2. User U1 is with Role R1
3. U1 logs and can see the Account through Account sharing rule
4. Clicks on Add button in Account team
5. Able to see User and Roles but not the Account Access setting. Please see the screenshot given[image]
6. But as per the Salesforce document, http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004250&language=en_US
   I should be able to set the Account Access when I add a new team member.  Let us now keep aside the opportunity and Case access but bare minimum I should be able to give Account Access as though Sharing rule I have read-write access.

Please let me know if I am missing any steps.

Thanks.